# Delay transition between routes

Tags: vue.js

I want to make a delay before triggering the next page when clicking a link opening a new route.

So I want the current page to fade out - then wait a small second before starting the fadeIn of the next page.

Current Transition below using Animate.css's Fade library.

```
<transition leave-active-class="animated fadeOut" enter-active-class="animated fadeInDown">
    <router-view></router-view>
</transition>
```

It's working nicely, but the change of page is too instant. The two routes are intersecting/fading into each others.

I want a clean fadeout -> full blank -> then open new page.

How to achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the transition mode from the default to `out-in` (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Modes)

```
<transition 
  mode="out-in" 
  leave-active-class="animated fadeOut" 
  enter-active-class="animated fadeInDown">
    <router-view></router-view>
</transition>
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what i wanted. Thanks